# OpenShift Pod gets stuck in pending state

Tags: mysql, openshift, kubernetes

MySQL pod in OpenShift gets stuck after new deployment and shows the message "The pod has been stuck in the pending state for more than five minutes." What can I do to solve this? I tried to scale the current deployment pod to 0 and scale the previous deployment pod to 1. But it also got stuck which was working earlier.

Comment: Are you using a persistent volume with the database? What OpenShift instance is this own? Your own or the OpenShift Online developer preview? What error messages show up in the events stream?

Comment: It's OpenShift developer preview. And appliation is mysql-persistent database. So it's persistent volume.

Comment: What shows up for ``oc get events``? There has been some problems earlier today with pulling Docker images to nodes which has been affecting deployment of applications. Am not sure if this was always occurring, or only when applications were deployed to specific nodes. For my test application the problem resolved with a later redeployment. If you are still seeing problems and it relates to pulling images, then report an issue via the Bugzilla issue tracker noted in the support page at https://docs.openshift.com/online/getting_started/devpreview_faq.html#devpreview-faq-support

Comment: Thanks Graham but I have actually reinstalled the MySQL template now. I will ask again if problem arises.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: No. I didn't have done much work at that time so I reinstalled it. Now I am not using since then so don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If pod stuck in pending state we can remove it by executing

`oc delete pod/<name of pod> --grace-period=0`

This command would remove pods immediately, but use it with caution because it may leave some process pid files on persistent volumes.